# How to install Python packages to (Homebrew) Ansible's site-packages folder

Tags: mac-osx, ansible

I have installed Ansible (v1.4.4) and Python (2.7.6) via Homebrew. I'm creating an Ansible playbook for setting up a local development machine on Mac (Mavericks). When I get to the step to import a MySQL database using the mysql_db module, Ansible complains "the python mysqldb module is required". So I installed it with pip (from Hombrew): `pip install MySQL-python`. After re-running, I get the same error message. The output of `cat /usr/local/bin/ansible-playbook` is

```
#!/bin/bash
PYTHONPATH="/usr/local/Cellar/ansible/1.4.4/libexec/lib/python2.7/site-packages" exec "/usr/local/Cellar/ansible/1.4.4/libexec/bin/ansible-playbook" "$@"
```

Installing with pip puts the packages in "`/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages`", but Ansible has its own site-packages folder so the global packages don't interfere with what Ansible requires. 
What's the best way to install to MySQL-python to Ansible's site-packages folder?

Comment: To solve the issue behind this question, I've started installing Ansible through pip in a virtual environment, which has given me the added benefit of freezing versions for different projects.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[By default, Ansible will use the Python install at `/usr/bin/python`](http://docs.ansible.com/faq.html#how-do-i-handle-python-pathing-not-having-a-python-2-x-in-usr-bin-python-on-a-remote-machine) unless you tell it otherwise. If you want it to use Homebrew Python, just add this to your inventory file:

`[local]

localhost ansible_python_interpreter=/usr/local/bin/python`

Answer (score 4):

If you need to use a package on the OSX control machine you will need to run these two lines after `brew install ansible`

```
mkdir -p ~/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages
echo '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages' > ~/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/homebrew.pth
```

https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/29079

I needed this on my control machine to encrypt [prompted variables](http://docs.ansible.com/playbooks_prompts.html) using Passlib

Answer (score 1):

Neither of the above answers worked for me; probably something to do with Yosemite.

The following worked for me:

```
PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/Cellar/ansible/1.8.2/libexec/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ \
  easy_install -ad ${PYTHONPATH} passlib
```

After this, I was able to enter encrypted passwords into `var_prompt`'s.

Answer (score 1):

In Homebrew ansible use own python. You can package library with the command

```
/usr/local/Cellar/ansible/2.2.1.0/libexec/bin/pip install MySQL-python
```